# Redact parts of an audio file using python (FFMPEG)

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, ffmpeg

I have a use case where I need to dynamically redact parts of an audio file using python. For example sometimes I may have to remove between timestamps 10 to 15 and other times between 5 to 7, 12 to 16 and 21 to 26 . I have tried looking at FFMPEG and think it may be possible with filters or chaining filters, but I am having trouble figuring out which ones to use and the combination. Any help or pointers will be highly appreciated. TIA!

Comment: One method is to use atrim, asetpts, and concat filters. Several examples on this site. Search `[ffmpeg] is:answer atrim asetpts concat`